# Ссылки и временные объекты

Tags: c++

Есть такой код:

```
#include <iostream>

void test(const int& val)
{
    const_cast<int&>(val) = 42;   
}

int main()
{
    int   val1 = 0, val2 = 0, val3 = 0;

    test(val1);
    test(val2 + 0);
    test(static_cast<int>(val3)); //Интересная строка;

    std::cout << val1 << " " << val2 << " " << val3 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

[Вывод GCC](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5189af7a6d0f434d):

```
42 0 0
```

[Вывод MS Visual Studio](https://rextester.com/URHE26201):

```
42 0 42
```

Кто прав и почему?

Comment: Забавно, но на VC++ 2017 (19.16.27032.1 для x64) никак не удается получить 42 - только 0...

Comment: Это явно баг компилятора, так как в третьем варианте использования вы должны получить новое значение после каста

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37969114/6944845

Comment: @Harry, `/permissive-` уберите, тогда получите.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. `static_cast<int>(val3)`, согласно [[expr.static.cast]p1](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.static.cast#1), является rvalue-выражением.
2. Согласно [[dcl.init.ref]p5.3](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.ref#5.3), инициализация константной ссылки rvalue-выражением проводит материализацию prvalue, создавая *константный* временный объект и привязывая ссылку к нему.
3. [[dcl.type.cv]p4](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.cv#4) явно запрещает нам модифицировать константные объекты.

Исходя из всех этих пунктов, правильный ответ будет `42 0 0`, но т.к. во втором и третьем случае мы имеем неопределённое поведение, то и вывод может быть любым. В результате, разговор о правильном ответе, в целом, не имеет смысла.

Тем не менее студия выводит `42 0 42` не из-за UB, а потому что без флага `/permissive-` срабатывает её расширение, которое игнорирует `static_cast`, когда тип не меняется. В результате в третьем случае передается lvalue, а не rvalue. Но это поведение противоречит стандарту и является расширением MSVC, которое, я полагаю, существует для некоторой обратной совместимости.

Comment: Почему второе это UB? Мы творим ересь с результатом сложения, но на слогаемых она никак не должна отразиться.

Comment: @ДмитрийЗиненко результат сложения это prvalue выражение.

Comment: Ощущение такое, что неопределенность поведения все же не должна относиться к самим исходным переменным, нет? Ну, конечно, с одной стороны, UB он и есть U, но не настолько же U  :) Т.е. в рамках функции - да, но за ее пределами? А prvalue никак с переменными напрямую не связан... Т.е. с тем же успехом `val3` может становиться 42 и при вызове `test(val1)` или `test(0)`...

Comment: @Harry, конечно, я увлёкся и написал ерунду. Исправил.